# `latexmk` running in terminal but not in neovim with `vimtex` after switching to native TeXLive installer

Tags: compiling, latexmk, vim

I start by giving some Arch-related context, but the question remains about `vimtex` and `latexmk`.

Yesterday, I tried updating my computer on Arch. I got an error

```bash
installing texlive-core (2023.66587-1) breaks dependency 'texlive-core<2023' required by tllocalmgr
```

(or something quite similar). [This link](https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/126m0er/texlivecore_breaks_dependency_required_by/) suggested I remove `tllocalmgr`, update/upgrade then reinstall `tllocalmgr`.

However, this solution didn't work. `tllocalmgr` is no longer working, and I was having a hard time using `latexmk` with `tlmgr`. Ultimately, I deleted all of my `texlive` packages from `pacman`, cleaned all `texlive`, and then reinstalled the native `texlive` in `perl` only, which seems to be the more robust approach (see [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/TeX_Live#Native_TeX_Live)). This way, **latexmk works from the terminal**.

My `vimtex` integration in `neovim` remains broken though. `:checkhealth` gives a clean output, I do **not** have a "latexmk is not executable" (well, anymore). I can use everything it allows for editing (math zones, environments delimiters, toggling fractions…), but compiling fails without creating a log file. MWE:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Compiling fails.

\end{document}
```

From `neovim` using `vimtex`, I only get a `.aux` with

```
\relax 
\gdef \@abspage@last{1}
```

and a `.fdb_latexmk` file with

```
# Fdb version 4
["pdflatex"] 1687213270 "test_random.tex" "test_random.pdf" "test_random" 1687213270 2
  (generated)
  "test_random.aux"
  "test_random.log"
  "test_random.pdf"
  (rewritten before read)
```

as contents.

From the terminal with `latexmk -pdf test_random.tex`, I get the same `.aux`, but the `.fdb_latexmk` reads

```
# Fdb version 4
["pdflatex"] 1687213361 "test_random.tex" "test_random.pdf" "test_random" 1687213362 0
  "/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb" 1248133631 35752 024fb6c41858982481f6968b5fc26508 ""
  "/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls" 1686341992 20144 fbcf51733730d8f1a62143512ff5b1fe ""
  "/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo" 1686341992 8448 74078c4a887f2cdcd57c3ec111622740 ""
  "/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def" 1681935207 29940 9473d58112bc8a88f5505b823a053dde ""
  "/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf" 1681165822 40967 d940221f8762fd5848760382d97d1226 ""
  "/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map" 1687134019 4643411 5ced174c6d521e21dd58a10751c00482 ""
  "/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex.fmt" 1687134040 7903677 2d412a3b911ee16f5c4df729eb70373f ""
  "/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf.cnf" 1687134016 455 5b996dcaa0eb4ef14a83b026bc0a008c ""
  "test_random.aux" 1687213362 32 3985256e7290058c681f74d7a3565a19 "pdflatex"
  "test_random.tex" 1687213261 76 405d82d3ea6d1935f53b22157943c78c ""
  (generated)
  "test_random.aux"
  "test_random.log"
  "test_random.pdf"
  (rewritten before read)
```

and I get a `.fls` and `.log` files.

I tried reinstalling `vimtex`, but to no avail. My configuration file `vimtex.lua` using `lazyvim` is

```
return {
  {
    "lervag/vimtex",
    ft = "tex", -- without ft, it's not working too
    lazy = false,
    config = function()
      vim.g.vimtex_quickfix_enabled = 1
      vim.g.vimtex_syntax_enabled = 1
      vim.g.vimtex_quickfix_mode = 0
      vim.g.tex_flavor = "latex"
      vim.g.tex_conceal = "abdmg"
      vim.g.vimtex_compiler_method = "latexmk"
      vim.g.vimtex_view_method = "zathura"
      vim.g.latex_view_general_viewer = "zathura"
      vim.cmd("call vimtex#init()")
    end,
  },
}
```

My terminal `echo $PATH` and neovim's `echo $PATH` do not match though. My `latexmk` is located in `/usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux/latexmk`, which is in my terminal PATH. My neovim PATH is `/home/nora/.local/share/nvim/mason/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/home/nora/.dotnet/tools:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl`. This doesn't seem to be the root cause of the issue, as `vimtex` sees `latexmk` as an executable (even giving a `.fdb_latexmk` file).

I do not have a `.latexmkrc` file.

`nvim --version` outputs

```
NVIM v0.9.1
Build type: Release
LuaJIT 2.1.0-beta3

   system vimrc file: "$VIM/sysinit.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/nvim"
```

`:VimtexInfo` gives

```
System info:
  OS: Arch Linux
  Vim version: NVIM v0.9.1
  Has clientserver: true
  Servername: /run/user/1000/nvim.651391.0

VimTeX project: test_random
  base: test_random.tex
  root: /home/nora/Documents/Enseignement/Prepa/2022/figures_generales
  tex: /home/nora/Documents/Enseignement/Prepa/2022/figures_generales/test_random.tex
  main parser: fallback current file
  document class: article
  compiler: latexmk
    engine: -pdf
    options:
      -verbose
      -file-line-error
      -synctex=1
      -interaction=nonstopmode
    callback: 1
    continuous: 1
    executable: latexmk
    job: 
      jobid: 19
      output: /tmp/nvim.nora/CaXhwO/0
      cmd: max_print_line=2000 latexmk -verbose -file-line-error -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -pdf -pvc -view=none -e '$compiling_cmd = ($compiling_cmd ? $compiling_cmd . " ; " : "") . "echo vimtex_compiler_callback_compiling"' -e '$success_cmd = ($success_cmd ? $success_cmd . " ; " : "") . "echo vimtex_compiler_callback_success"' -e '$failure_cmd = ($failure_cmd ? $failure_cmd . " ; " : "") . "echo vimtex_compiler_callback_failure"' 'test_random.tex'
      pid: 0
  viewer: Zathura
    xwin id: 0
  qf method: LaTeX logfile
```

Thanks for any help you might give me!

Comment: Definitely. I do a full clean with `VimtexClean` beforehand. I can compile with just `pdflatex` in the terminal.

Comment: Could it be this: https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/issues/2735 ? Basically, install `texlive-binextra` package?

Comment: @Rmano Doesn't look like it, as my `latexmk` exists and runs. I had the `latexmk is not executable` error when I had both `texlive-bin` (etc) from `pacman` and texlive from the native installer, I guess pointing issues. Thus I'm a bit reluctant to redownload a `texlive` package from `pacman`.

Comment: Can you configure vimtex to use `pdflatex` rather than `latexmk`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I guess I could have but that would have been looking away from the issue: not a fan of that. The solution was much easier though: I just needed a fresh terminal instance to have my new TeXlive sourced.

Comment: @NoraNICOLAS Not a suggested fix, but potentially useful to identify if the problem is `latexmk`-specific

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue while stumbling upon another error launching a `.py` file with neovim (`kpathsea: configuration file texmf.cnf not found in these directories`), and it's unfortunately (or maybe, fortunately) a "dumb" one: I was launching my `.tex` files from the same instance of `ranger`, so it was not sourced.

Launching from a fresh terminal solved everything (although I still had to delete `tllocalmgr` etc beforehand, I had rebooted a few times during that process)… Well, now `vimtex` says `Compilation failed!` while the logs don't say it did and compilation works, but I'd rather have it this way around.